# How can I localize strings in Xaml files for WPFLocalizationExtension

Tags: wpf, xaml, localization

I'm using [WPFLocalizationExtension](https://github.com/SeriousM/WPFLocalizationExtension) to localize my WPF application. I'm very happy with the run-time behavior, but extracting string properties manually to ResX files is very tedious.

Is there a way to automate this? I used to have a tool called Xaml Localizer Addin that did exactly this (screenshot below), but it only works with VS2008 and I couldn't find a newer version.

[image]

Comment: You have the latest release of WPFLocalizationExtension and using .net 3.5? I seem to recall working on a project a few months ago that had it and I was using VS2013 fine.

Comment: @ChrisW. I'm using .NET 4; WPFLocalizationExtension is working fine, too. What I'm missing is a button in Visual Studio that says "move all localizable XAML attributes to resource".

Comment: I have a ~300kloc project, and I do *not* want to localize every XAML file by hand. I'd sooner write my own tool to extract strings, but I'd prefer using something that already exists.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using visual studio 2010, you may want to check out [Xaml Localization Tool](http://xlocalization.codeplex.com/). It's an extension for vs2010 to localize xaml application, and generate .resx files from xaml.

Another idea is to download [XAML Localize Source Code](https://xamllocalize.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) and build your own visual studio add-in or tool that is compatible with your version of .net.

Comment: Damn, both only support VS2010, right? (And are apparently abandoned projects.) I'm using VS2013, ideally would like to switch to VS2015 at some time. Other than that - that would be exactly what I'm looking for...

Comment: If you have vs2015 installed then you might be able to write your own v2013 add-in using the source code above (since i have vs2013 installed and i'm able to write add-ins for vs2010 using add-in project).

Comment: Even better! I can load my VS2013 project into VS2010! Thank you very much. You've earned the bounty.